# How do I get WGL to create a 32 bit depth buffer?

Tags: winapi, opengl

If I set `cDepthBits, cStencilBits` to `24, 8` it works fine, but `32, 0` doesn't. Here's what I'm doing:

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {0};
pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
pfd.nVersion = 1;
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 32;
pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
pfd.cStencilBits = 0;
pfd.dwLayerMask = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

i32 pixelFormatIndex = ChoosePixelFormat(windows.hdc, &pfd);
SetPixelFormat(windows.hdc, pixelFormatIndex, &pfd);
windows.hrc = wglCreateContext(windows.hdc);
wglMakeCurrent(windows.hdc, windows.hrc);
```

Then I query the PFD with `DescribePixelFormat(windows.hdc, GetPixelFormat(windows.hdc), ..)`, and `cDepthBits` is only 24.

Comment: Support for 32-bit depth buffers in the default framebuffer is very uncommon (even on hardware that supports them). If you need that sort of thing, you'd almost be better off using a Framebuffer Object with a 32-bit depth attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is unclear if your implementation actually does support a 32 bit depth buffer for the default framebuffer.

However, using the [WGL_ARB_pixel_format](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_pixel_format.txt) extension gives you much finer control over the pixel formats. Especially, `wglChoosePixelFormatARB()` will return a *set* of pixel formats mathcing (more or less strictly) the attributes you queried for. You can then iterate over those and use `wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB()`/`wglGetPixelFormatAttribfvARB()` to query for the detailed attributes of the returned formats, and select the one you like best - and you can check if any 32 bit depth format is among them.

Comment: Tried it, but it's not working so great. `wglGetProcAddress` fails before I create a context. What's the order you have to call these functions in? `ChoosePixelFormat` -> `SetPixelFormat` -> `wglCreateContext` -> `wglMakeCurrent` -> `wglGetProcAddress` -> `wglChoosePixelFormatARB` -> `SetPixelFormat`? Can I modify the pixel format of the current context?

Comment: You can't modify existing pixel formats. The windows API is very cumbersome at this point. You'll need to create some helper GL context and some helper window (which doesn't have to be visible, though) to get the wgl extensions and can then create a new window and context with the real aatributes you want to use. This ugly procedure is also required when you want a modern GL context or a default framebuffer with multisampling via wgl.

Comment: Yea, ok, I think I'll stick to the 24 bit buffer for now... Thanks though.